# Два столбца в одном блоке

Tags: html

Немного истории.

Сам в программировании не смыслю, абсолютно. Не так давно семьей решили открыть турагенство. Открыли, работает, не так хорошо, как хотелось бы, и решили, что нужно сделать сайт. Так как бюджет был небольшим, то решил воспользоваться конструктором сайтов. Только теперь понимаю, какой это было ошибкой. Там было расписано, что мне останется только лишь заполнить блоки, и все будет хорошо, и для этого не нужно знать никаких языков программирования. При первой же проблеме техподдержка мне ответила, что необходимо знать css, javascript, html.
С горем пополам чутка разобрался в форматировании текстов, создании спойлеров и в таких несложных вещах.

Суть вопроса.

Так как блоки не двигаются, мне нужно в одном из блоков сделать так, чтобы информер с погодой и обмен валют были расположены по горизонтали, а не друг за другом по вертикали, поэтому прошу помощи. Если кто-то знает, как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

В приложении 2 скрина, на одном расположение блоков, и там видно пустое место между погодой и вк, как раз туда и нужно разместить обменник.
На втором скрине как выглядит окно, которое появляется при нажатии на html-вкладку, на каждом блоке.

**Обновление**

Подскажите, а куда вставлять код информеров? В конструкторе, когда жмешь на готовый блок, дальше выбираешь режим html, открывается пустое окно. Получается скопировать

```
.block-1 {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
}
```

Дальше код информера и снова

```
.block-2 {
   display: inline-block;
   float: left;
}
```

Так?

**Обновление 2**

Ребят, я очень благодарен вам за ответы, но так как я писал выше, я туго соображаю в том, что вы говорите. Покопавшись с float получил, вот что:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>float</title>
  <style>
   .layer1 {
    float: left; /* Обтекание по правому краю */
    background: #fd0; /* Цвет фона */
    border: 1px solid black; /* Параметры рамки */
    padding: 10px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
    margin-right: 20px; /* Отступ справа */
    width: 40%; /* Ширина блока */
   }
  </style>
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div class="layer1">
 ПОГОДА
  </div>
  <div>ВАЛЮТА</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/524jtm09/ - float

http://jsfiddle.net/qznztqbr/ - display-inline

http://jsfiddle.net/mmgfpx2u/ - display: table

Answer (score 0):

Приветствую!

Чтобы блочные элементы располагались друг за другом, им требуется задать следующие css-атрибуты (пример):

```
.block-1 {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}

.block-2 {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}
```

Comment: Роман, большое спасибо за ответ, подскажите а куда вставлять код информеров? в конструкторе когда жмешь на готовый блок, дальше выбираешь режим html открывается пустое окно. Получается скопировать 
.block-1 {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}
дальше код информера и снова

.block-2 {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}


так?

Comment: Нет. Пример, что я описал выше - всего лишь пример. Это css-стили, которые нужно задать вашим блокам.

Нужно узнать, какие классы используют эти блоки, и этим классам задать эти стили.

Comment: `display:inline-block` и `float` два свойства которые противоречат друг другу. `Float` по хорошему применяется только к блочным объектам.

Comment: используйте одно из этих свойств - или display: inline-block или float: left; 
для последнего необходимо будет задать clearfix.

Comment: ребят я очень благодарен вам за ответы, но так как я писал выше я туго соображаю в том что вы говорите. покапавшись с float получил вот что:
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>float</title>
  <style>
   .layer1 {
    float: left; /* Обтекание по правому краю */
    background: #fd0; /* Цвет фона */
    border: 1px solid black; /* Параметры рамки */
    padding: 10px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
    margin-right: 20px; /* Отступ справа */
    width: 40%; /* Ширина блока */
   }
  </style>
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div class="layer1">
 ПОГОДА
  </div>
  <div>ВАЛЮТА</div>
 </body>
</html>